# Is the "not an answer" flag discouraged?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a post (which had already attracted downvotes and a "this isn't an answer" comment) as "not an answer", and it was declined because "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".  What is that flag reason for?  I don't have the rep to vote to delete.

I'm not concerned about the flag, but I'd like to know what behavior is expected.

Comment: I think you'll need to get a response from the mod who declined the flag.  I personally consider flagging as not an answer something that is encouraged, but we haven't discussed it as a mod team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not discouraged. Please continue flagging! I'm the mod that declined the flag. I agree that this answer you flagged was pretty bad: It was more of an off-topic ramble than an answer. However, it *is* an answer.

The "not an answer" flag is usually used to indicate comments by new users left as answers. This answer was on the long side, it wouldn't have fit into a comment. In this case, it was good of you to bring this to the attention of the mods, even though I declined the flag.

I indicated to the system that the flag was helpful after dismissing it. It won't adversely affect your flag weight.

I downvoted the answer and left a comment, to help this user learn from this. My question for you: Why didn't you downvote this answer?

Comment: I think we may be talking about two different flags.  (I didn't mean the one you commented on.)  Err, should I name names, so to speak?  I'm mindful of not embarrassing the posters and don't know the etiquette.  I thought I had downvoted but see that I didn't; fixing that now.  I didn't downvote the one you commented on because I thought it could be redeemed.